# How to Google Takeout my Shared Drives? (in 2020)

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, google-shared-drive, google-takeout

I have spent days migrating all our files into shared drives in Google Drive. After doubling the cost of our service to allow shared drives.

Now how do I download all those files as part of Google Takeout?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I would think that option would only be available to G Suite administrators, since the files are owned by the organisation. Are you an administrator?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an administrator in G Suite for any organization, so I can't see.

Comment: Yes, I'd an admin