# How to backup all files from G Suite Shared Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-shared-drive

I have lots of Docs and Sheets on G Suite Shared Drives.

Previously before I upgraded to Shared Drives, I had this in a folder in My Drive. Previously I could back this up by using Google Takeout.

Now how do I do this when my files on Shared Drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Google Takeout my Shared Drives? (in 2020)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/141443/how-to-google-takeout-my-shared-drives-in-2020)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to help our Admin team set up Takeout for our shared drive.

Comment: Google support recommended me to use Google Vault. This exports all of your files into one big zipball without any directory structure. It's the dumbest f— thing I heard all day. Next I am now looking into rclone, but that requires me to set up every drive separately and not sure if it actually works yet.